# Selected index in ListBox dosent stay selected after getting values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, methods, indexing, listbox

I want to be able to select an index on my ListBox.My ListBox is getting getting values depending on the selected index, however when I try to select an index in the listbox, it gets the values but  stays unselected. I have to select the index a second time for it to be selected. Why is that?

here is my code on the selectedIndexChanged:

```
Private Sub listResults_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles listResults.SelectedIndexChanged
    UpdateContactInformationFromRegistry()
End Sub
```

The UpdateContactInformationFromRegistry() method:

```
 Private Sub UpdateContactInformationFromRegistry()
        Dim contact As Contact = m_contacts.GetContact(listResults.SelectedIndex)

        cmbCountries.SelectedIndex = DirectCast(contact.AddressData.Country, Integer)
        txtFirstName.Text = contact.FirstName
        txtLastName.Text = contact.LastName
        txtStreet.Text = contact.AddressData.Street
        txtZip.Text = contact.AddressData.ZipCode
        txtCity.Text = contact.AddressData.City

    End Sub
```

UPDATE V2

cmbCountries.SelectedIndexChanged event handler

```
 Private Sub cmbCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbCountries.SelectedIndexChanged
        UpdateGUI()
    End Sub
```

UpdateGUI() method

```
Private Sub UpdateGUI()
        Dim strContacts() As String = m_contacts.GetContactInfo()



        If (strContacts IsNot Nothing) Then
            listResults.Items.Clear()
            listResults.Items.AddRange(strContacts)
            lstCount.Text = listResults.Items.Count.ToString()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have an event handler associated to cmbCountries.SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: Yes. Please see the updated information on the question

Comment: when you clear the list in UpDateGUI you also clear selected items. make your list the DataSource for the ListBox and most of that code is not needed

Comment: How can I make the list the DataSource?

Comment: add a method to the collection class passing the listbox (maybe pass it in the ctor) then just `theListBox.DataSource = theList`  a BindingList<T> might work better though

Comment: Its hard to do that in my situation. I like the way I was doing even tho I don't know how to get through the "Item.Clear" problem, is there any way to avoid clearing the selected index in UpdateGUI?

Comment: I fixed it. i just removed the cmbCountries.SelectedIndexChanged event handler and it worked perfectly